# How do I use for loops to output this box in python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I've already tried this and it's not working.

```
def drawBox(size):  
        for j in range(size, -1, -1):
            for k in range(j):
                print((j), end = "")
                print("x" * (size - j))
```

This is my desired output:

```
666666x
55555xx
4444xxx
333xxxx
22xxxxx
1xxxxxx
```

Comment: Look at your current output and think about why it appears like it does. (Probably [edit] your question to show what your current code prints.)

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
def drawBox(size):  
        for j in range(size, 0, -1):
            print((j*str(j)).ljust(size+1,'x'))
```